# Interpolation plugin error message WKB access out of bounds with QGIS 2.14 & 2.18

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I am new to QGIS.

I am trying to construct a DEM from contour lines by using QGIS 2.14.0. (and later 2.18) I am doing this by using a clip rectangle tool (geoprocessing tools) on top of the contour lines and interpolating, by using the interpolation plugin, using triangular interpolation.

After I enter the data in the interpolation dialog and clic Save  I get an
exception "WKB access out of bounds".

Someone suggested that to avoid getting this error, it's better to interpolate before clipping the image, but doing this causes QGIS to doing a massive processing taking a huge amount of time.

Has anyone run into this and managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I could escape this error by cleaning the clipped contour lines before interpolation.

To clean the contour, I used `Processing | GRASS | Vector | v.clean` tool.

[image]

The attached image shows **chdangle** I often use, but it seems any of these cleaning tools works (at least *break*, *snap*, *rmdangle*, and *chdangle* as far as I know.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. What is the cleaning all about?

Comment: @AntonioScotti it means the clipping contour creates topological error, which is troublesome to triangular algorithm.